# Display user ID in the metrics of application Insight

Tags: azure-application-insights

This page
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage-custom-events-metrics/#authenticated-users

Show how to have login information in the section "Authenticated users".

But how can I see this information in Application Insight after that

Answer (score 2):

I do not see user anywhere in the custom event properties for events, it seems to be the internal field that's collected but not directly exposed in the view because most of the time this "auto-collected" user would be simply an auto-generated GUID....

You can take a look at the users summary on "Usage Analytics/Users" view as well as in Metric Explorer (just select the metrics about app users like "user accounts"...)

You should be able to search for user in the Diagnostic Search but only if you specify the user name you are looking for in the search - you'll get events/traces and so on for that particular user.

Also, you can try to submit authenticated user as a custom property on the event instead of (in addition to) the embedded property, in this case you should definitely see if as part of the properties in UI but this leads to a duplication of the value inside the event (internal + custom)...

Comment: Because it's only a preview, thing change fast, maybe the property are not public for now.

In the documentation they told us where to find it, but it's not there 
 "To see the resulting data in Application Insights, create new charts in Metric Explorer to display the Users and User Accounts metrics."

Comment: For now, after a user log to the system I add a custom event to keep the username. When I select this event, I can track every page he go in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query with [Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour). The result of your query should return a column called `user_AuthenticatedId`.

Comment: In my case user_AuthenticatedId column is not capturing any data.  I confirmed this in Analytics where both user_AuthenticatedId and user_AccountId for all applications monitored are blank.  user_Id column has data but it is anonymized.

Comment: @motionpotion - were you able to get Auth Id filled in? Seems like user_id isn't very useful...