# Azure application Log

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Web app.
As I understand there is a service within Azure that will give insight into user activity.
For instance, A user is making a selection in within the app and selects "save". In the inspection mode of the browser we can clearly see this action, see screenshot. I would like to se the same information within Azure.
This will give me a better understating of what the user has gone through and therefor I can help by better understanding the situation.

Unfortunately, I do not know where this service is. Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand there is a service within Azure that will give insight into user activity

Yes, you can see the all-user activities in an **Azure** ***Application insights Portal.***

In your **Application Insights -> Usage panel -> Users** tab we can find the user details in a chart pattern
[image]
If you want to get the detailed information you have to send the user telemetry information in a custom Telemetry in Application Insights.

- You have to send your **user information (Telemetry)** to the Application Insights in both **Client and Server App**. For that you have to use the **custom telemetry** to send all your **user information into Application Insights**.

[image]

#### References

- [Sending user information to Applicaiton Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988481/azure-app-insights-how-to-track-the-logged-in-username-in-auth-id)
- [Adding Request body into application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686363/view-post-request-body-in-application-insights)
- [Send telemetry from your App to Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-overview)

Comment: thank you for reply.
What I do not understand is why I need to send telemetry separately when the backend is already receives requested from the frontend. Also the front and backend are the one and same web application. So, I am thing that the information is already in app. insight.
Also, to send telemetry from the front end to application insight means I need to expose the token to the frontend, and that is a big security risk.
I am looking for help for this so I still need to learn a few things, so correct me when you thing I have the wrong understanding of the material.

Comment: Hi @Phyxius, normally application insights collect all the telemetry data. If you want to retrieve or send specific information you have to send it to custom telemetry.